# Прямая речь в предложении - когда это член предложения?

Tags: прямая-речь

> -Хочу посмотреть нынешний детдом, - отвлеклась от своего рассказа Лепестинья.

Можно это предложение охарактеризовать, как простое, осложненное прямой речью?

Если нет, то как?

Answer (score 2):

Да, но потом отдельно разобрать прямую речь как отдельное предложение: предложение повествовательное, невосклицательное, простое, двусоставное, распространенное, полное, осложнено прямой речью. Прямая речь представляет собой предложение повеств., невоскл., односоставное,неопр.-личное, распространенное, полное, неосложненное...

Прямая речь является членом предложения, если восполняет какой-либо недостающий член:"Иду!"- послышалось из окна. При разборе главного предложения мы говорим, что это неполное двусоставное с пропуском подлежащего, чью позицию занимает прямая речь.

Comment: В школьном курсе предложений с прямой речью нет ни  среди простых, ни среди сложных. Посмотрите, вот здесь есть интересное, на мой взгляд, обсуждение вопроса в связи с заданиями на ЕГЭ. 


[Здесь][1]


  [1]: http://rus-exam.ru/forum/4--pro-18---/441-4-----